# Spring data jpa - How to make a selection on children and output the parents with all selected children?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mapstruct

I have thoses entities

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "CITY")
public class CityEntity {
    @Id private int id;
    private String name;
    private String postcode;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) @JoinColumn(name="ID_CITY_FK") 
    private List<SchoolEntity> schools;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "SCHOOL")
public class SchoolEntity {
    @Id private int id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) @JoinColumn(name="ID_CITY_FK") 
    private CityEntity city;
}
```

I would like to make a selection based on the school name and have an output like

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Paris",
    "postcode": "75000",
    "schools": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Java School 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Java School 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Brussels",
    "postcode": "1000",
    "schools": [
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Java School 3"
      },
      {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Java School 4"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I think the only way is starting from the school entity

```
public interface SchoolEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<SchoolEntity, Integer> {
    List<SchoolEntity> findByNameContaining(String name);
}
```

then with my controller I can retrieve the schools

```
@GetMapping("/from-school")
public List<City> fromSchool2() {
    List<SchoolEntity> schoolEntities = schoolEntityRepository.findByNameContaining("Java");
    return ...;
}
```

and I also a Mapstruct mapper

```
@Mapper
public interface CityEntityMapper {
    CityEntityMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CityEntityMapper.class);
    List<City> map(List<SchoolEntity> schools);
}
```

But then ... ?  I have no idea on how to do that ?

Comment: Just write a query which returns what you need. This can be either from the `City` or the `School`. Something like `SELECT s.city FROM school s WHERE s.name LIKE :name`. Will give you all the cities from the school. You might need a distinct in there to get single cities only. Of something like `SELECT c FROM city c JOIN c.schools s WHERE s.name LIKE :name`. Either should work. Don't be afraid to use a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Fetch the SchoolEntity instances based on the school name using the SchoolEntityRepository.

```
public interface SchoolEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<SchoolEntity, Integer> {
    List<SchoolEntity> findByNameContaining(String name);
}
```

###### Group the schools by their associated CityEntity

```
@GetMapping("/from-school")
public List<City> fromSchool2() {
    List<SchoolEntity> schoolEntities = schoolEntityRepository.findByNameContaining("Java");

    // Group schools by city
    Map<CityEntity, List<SchoolEntity>> schoolsByCity = schoolEntities.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SchoolEntity::getCity));

    // Convert the map entries to City DTOs
    return schoolsByCity.entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> CityEntityMapper.INSTANCE.cityEntityToCity(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

###### Map the resulting data structure to the desired DTO structure using MapStruct

```
@Mapper
public interface CityEntityMapper {
    CityEntityMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CityEntityMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source = "city.name", target = "name")
    @Mapping(source = "city.postcode", target = "postcode")
    @Mapping(source = "schools", target = "schools")
    City cityEntityToCity(CityEntity city, List<SchoolEntity> schools);
}
```

DTO's:

```
@Data
public class City {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String postcode;
    private List<School> schools;
}

@Data
public class School {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```